# llncs - table lined up with section heading

Tags: tables, sectioning, lncs

I want to have the first line of a table line up with the section heading.  I'm preparing the document for Springer's LNCS series using the [llncs.cls](http://tqc.quantumlah.org/lncs) house style. Here's how things look if I do this without any adjustment:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Forces}

\begin{tabular}{p{.85\textwidth}}
\textbf{Threshold}: there is a tension between inclusiveness and specificity.\\
\textbf{Trust}: is only built through sharing and reciprocity.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: default layout in llncs class]

For comparison, here's how it looks with the standard `article` class.  This isn't what I'm after either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Forces}

\begin{tabular}{p{.85\textwidth}}
\textbf{Threshold}: there is a tension between inclusiveness and specificity.\\
\textbf{Trust}: is only built through sharing and reciprocity.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: default layout in article class]

---

What I'm after is something like:

> **Forces**  **Threshold**: there is a tension between inclusiveness and specificity
>
> **Trust**: is only built through sharing and reciprocity

---

## What I tried:

The following hack:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Forces}

\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}
{{\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{.85\textwidth}}
\textbf{Threshold}: there is a tension between inclusiveness and specificity.\\
\textbf{Trust}: is only built through sharing and reciprocity.
\end{tabular}

\par}}

\end{document}
```

This is close but the vertical aligment seems to be slightly off.

[image: close but seems off]

---

xref: [How to align the left edge of text in table with the section heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256135/how-to-align-the-left-edge-of-text-in-table-with-the-section-heading) deals with horizontal alignment of tables, I want vertical alignment.

Comment: why use `\begin{tabular}{p{.85\textwidth}}` instead of `\parbox{.85\textwidth}` ? there is only one column so no alignment so `tabular` isn't doing anything very useful.

Comment: but  just use `\begin{tabular}[t]` to align on the top instead of centre.

Comment: `\parbox` has the same problem with vertical alignment relative to the section heading.

Comment: yes it has the same `[t]` option to specify top alignment as well:-)

Comment: OK, that's sorted out.  If you want to make this an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabular` (or you could more simply use `\parbox`) are vertically centred by default, but they both take an optional argument to specify vertical alignment, so `\begin{tabular}[t]`... will do what you need here.